# Java application is working without kinit but nodejs application using node-rdkafka library is not working without kinit

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kerberos, librdkafka

I am using **https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka** for my node.js application where I want to connect to Kafka usingkeytab file and below mechanism.

```
'security.protocol':'sasl_plaintext',
'sasl.mechanisms':'GSSAPI',
```

I don't have kinit in my application server and java based applications are working without using kinit.
We used `jass.config` in Java to provide details like `renewTGT=false doNotPrompt=true useKeyTab=true`

Is there similar config in node-rdkafka which can be used and we can avoid kinit command?

Comment: It's been years since I used Kerberos, but my understanding is that kinit is always required to get a valid certificate + keytab on the OS. It is not language specific... I suggest you look at the standard librdkafka configuration, not node specific repo

Comment: Thanks. I installed kinit for node.js app in server and it worked with that.